# Syntax error: invalid syntax. File "<stdin">, line 1

Tags: python, web

I have just started python and stuck in this error. While typing python helloworld.py this error is occurring My helloworld.py file is openning in windows cmd but it's not opening in python.exe

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add the code that is producing the error in order to reproduce it and how you're calling the file in the command line. Please consider reading up on [what an MCRE is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please edit your question and delete the comments

Comment: Thankyou so much for your kind attention!! But I've cracked it ,it needed to specify path